# How do I clone an entire database from one Postgres instance, to become a part of a database hosted on a different instance?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL instance `A` with 10 tables, and another instance `B` hosted on a different box, which contains the same 10 tables but also many others. I'd like to clone all 10 tables from the small database `A` to overwrite their equivalents in the larger database `B`. What's a good way to do this?

One path I'm considering is to do a full `pg_dump` of `A`, copy that dump file to `B`'s host, then `pg_restore` it into `B`. It seems like it should work since I do want every single table on `A` to overwrite the table of the same name on `B`, but I'm just a bit nervous doing a `pg_restore` of a full database dump, and I'm also not very familiar with `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` so it would be great to have that plan validated by someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plain format `pg_dump` with the `--clean` option and specify the tables you want to dump with `-t`.

Then you get an SQL script that contains only the tables you want replaced, and each table is preceeded with a `DROP TABLE`.

You can check the script before using it.

Comment: How should I use the resulting SQL script?

Comment: With `psql -h ... -d ... -U ... -f dump. sql`.